# [iOS]: Run project on sitmulator failed

Tags: ios, logging, compiler-errors

I has built my project and run it on simulator. It showed error

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)
```

I checked system log. It showed:

```
Jun  8 16:53:08  com.apple.dt.Xcode[29826] <Error>: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/duong/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A980FDBA-E61F-4ED6-9F43-2C30DB071222/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Xf5A16/extracted/xxx.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework}
```

How could I fix that? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

please follow these steps
1. reset simulator
2 delete derived data
3 clean Xcode and try again